# Node JS Remote execution of App script code failing

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-oauth

I am trying to execute an app script function using Node JS. Here is what I have done so far in order *(The full code snippet is posted at the bottom of this)* :

1. I created a google cloud project. I enabled  the Google Drive API and App Script API. After doing that, I created credentials for desktop app, by going to `API & services -> credentials -> create credentials -> oAuth client ID`. I downloaded the json file and named it as `credentials.json` and placed it in my working directory. I also set up the OAuth consent screen.
2. In my working directory I run `"npm install googleapis@39 --save"` to install the client library. After that I create a file called `"index.js"` and use the code snippet provided in this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/nodejs). The function `"callAppsScript"` I replace it with the function avaliable [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#node.js) under Node.js. I also edit the code to put the scope below :

```js
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
```

3. I create An app script project and change the google cloud platform project to a standard one and set it to use the GCP project I created in the first step. Now in my App script project i create a function called `"getFoldersUnderRoot"` and copy the code at this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#node.js), which is avaliable at the bottom as target script. I also get the App script project ID and replace it in my `index.js` file I created in step 2.
4. I set the following scope in my `appscript.json` file :

```js
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"
  ],
```

5. I now deploy my apps script project as an API executable. And in my working directory i run `"node index.js"`. I am able to authenticate my self and the `token.js` file is even generated. However, When the `"callAppsScript"` function is called I am constantly getting this error:

***Requested entity was not found.***

Please view my entire code snippet below. I have intentionally removed script ID here.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');


const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];

const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';


fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), callAppsScript);
});


function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  console.log(client_id);
  console.log(client_secret);
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);


  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
     
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}


function callAppsScript(auth) {  
  console.log(auth);
  const scriptId = '******';
  const script = google.script('v1');


  script.scripts.run({
    auth: auth,
    resource: {
      function: 'getFoldersUnderRoot',
    },
    scriptId: scriptId,
  }, function(err, resp) {
    if (err) {

      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    if (resp.error) {

      const error = resp.error.details[0];
      console.log('Script error message: ' + error.errorMessage);
      console.log('Script error stacktrace:');

      if (error.scriptStackTraceElements) {

        for (let i = 0; i < error.scriptStackTraceElements.length; i++) {
          const trace = error.scriptStackTraceElements[i];
          console.log('\t%s: %s', trace.function, trace.lineNumber);
        }
      }
    } else {
    
      const folderSet = resp.response.result;
      if (Object.keys(folderSet).length == 0) {
        console.log('No folders returned!');
      } else {
        console.log('Folders under your root folder:');
        Object.keys(folderSet).forEach(function(id) {
          console.log('\t%s (%s)', folderSet[id], id);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I have gone through the documentation for almost 3 days and tried everything. Please help me out.

Comment: Although from your question, I'm not sure about your Google Apps Script, in your situation, when you save the Google Apps Script at the script editor using the save button again and test it again, what result will you obtain? When I had the same situation, this method was the solution. But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this. So I posted this as a comment.

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks for the suggestion. I have saved it before and tried many times. It doesn't seem to be fixing my issue. If its not too much trouble, do let me know if your previous code to execute App script functions remotely with node JS still works.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Hi there @celEstiic 7! I wasn't able to replicate this issue as is. Could you share the [minimal amount](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code that reproduces the problematic behaviour so we all can take a look? To discard a project misconfiguration, could you please clarify if this issue is reproducible from a blank new project?